# Submit button points to wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I am building a form to work with a non activerecord model.  I have two problems..

1. When I point to keyword/id/edit my form's submit button says 'create keyword', and pressing that submit button takes me to the create method on my keyword controller. It should be taking me to the update action.
2. I would also like to send an attribute called 'id' to my update action. I'm not sure how to do this. Like I said this isn't an activerecord model.

/views/keywords/_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@keyword) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :name %><br />

    <%= f.text_field :name %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :keyword %><br />

    <%= f.text_field :keyword %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :message1 %><br />

    <%= f.text_area :message1 %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :message2 %><br />

    <%= f.text_area :message2 %>

  </div>

    <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :start_time %><br />

    <%= f.text_area :start_time %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">

    <%= f.submit %>

  </div>

 <% end %>
```

/controller/keywords_controller.rb >> edit action

```
def edit

    result = Keyword.find(params[:id])

    result = result.to_array(:get_response, :return, :data, :item)

    result = result.first

    @keyword = Keyword.new

    @keyword.id = result[:item][0][:value]

    @keyword.name = result[:item][1][:value]

    @keyword.keyword = result[:item][2][:value]

    @keyword.message1 = result[:item][3][:value]

    if(result[:item][4][:value] != {:"@xsi:type"=>"xsd:string"})

    @keyword.message2 = result[:item][4][:value]

    end

    @keyword.start_time = result[:item][5][:value]

end
```

/models/keyword.rb

```
    class Keyword 

   extend ActiveModel::Naming

  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def persisted?

    false

  end

    attr_accessor :id, :name, :keyword, :message1, :message2, :start_time
  def self.get_keywords(cid)
    #get data from webservice 
  end

  end
```

config/routes.rb

```
  SchoolBeacon::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  devise_for :admins

  resources :keywords

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@keyword = Keyword.new` line in your edit action to `@keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])` or however you find the keyword.  If you are using normal RESTful rails routes, that should do it.

Actually, you can just do `form_for(@keyword, :url => keyword_path(@result)` and change your result to an ivar(`result` becomes `@result`)

Comment: I tried it and got the following Routing Error `No route matches [POST] "/keywords/60836"`

Comment: do you have `resources :keywords` in your routes file? if not, or if you can, paste any routes that you have in your `config/routes.rb` file that contain the word keywords.  Maybe it was just a routing problem to begin with.

Comment: Checkout http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for and notice that `Resource-oriented style` section as it explains what the expanded html will look like in your browser.  Please check your generated code against that, and if your's doesn't look the same, you got problems elsewhere.  I assume you are on Rails 3.2, right?